# Octave plot with serial date

Tags: plot, octave

I generated next commands in Octave:

```
T=datenum(2016,1,1,0,(1:100*1440)',0); % half of year minute data
x=cumsum(randn(length(T),1));
plot(T,x)
```

and get very strange and unreal picture. But

```
plot(T-T(1),x)
```

is real curve. I don't understand - why?
GNU Octave Version: 4.0.2, Windows 8.1.
Thanks.

Comment: @Sergey, what is the problem exactly? Both outputs look fine to me. The first just reports the days in a "unix-timestamp" like manner, as "days since January 1st 0000", whereas the second reports difference in days from your first measurement, as you instructed it. Are you getting something different? Would you like to post a link of the image you're getting? (use imgur.com)

Comment: I uploaded 3 pictures to http://imgur.com/a/015Gp
plot(T,x), plot(T,x,'.-') and plot(T-T(1),x).
1st and 2nd are very strange for me, 3rd is expected. T is ordinary serial date, of course, but T-(T(1) is time from T(1) in days.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Mine both look like the bottom one. I tried both 4.0.2 and 4.0.3 (but on linux). Seems like a bug. The previous comment seems to have been deleted but it suggested that it is known behaviour of OpenGL (specific to windows perhaps?) because of float instead of double, and he suggested you try the gnuplot / fltk interface instead. (i.e. `graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')`). See `available_graphics_toolkits` for, uh, well, available graphics toolkits :p

Comment: I am a beginner at Octave, because some features is unknown to me... :-(

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou - I am a beginner at Octave, therefore some features are unknown to me... :-( I make graphics_toolkit gnuplot and plot(T,x) given good results. Of course, without facilities of work with graphics.

Comment: if it works as expected with a different toolkit, then this is a bug. Please consider letting the awesome octave devs know by submitting a bug at http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave (if you don't find a duplicate entry there first, that is). You could also try asking at the octave channel at irc://irc.freenode.net/octave if you're feeling chatty :)